# Best way to check every site, if it's online Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On every post I have url a website. I need get status and check every hour if this site is online. How I can do it with queues Laravel? I have a job CheckIfOnline:

```
public function handle(Post $post)
{

         if($this->checkOnline($post->site_url) {
              $post->website_online = true;
              $post->save();
         }

}

private function checkOnline($domain) {
    $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    //get answer
    $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

    curl_close($curlInit);
    if ($response) return true;
    return false;
}
```

In task:

```
 /**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
       foreach(Post::all() as $post) {
    CheckIfOnline::dispatch($post);
}
    })->hourly();
}
```

If I have 10,000 sites to check, thats going to take quite a long time.

How I can do this correctly? In database all sites are different. But I have more 10000+ different sites. I need to check every site if it's online, or at least once per day..

Comment: Use multithreading and a sensible timeout value :-)

Comment: and put it on the queue

Comment: I think you should utilize https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Comment: @grooveplex can you please give a example?

Comment: Well, I have never worked with Laravel before, so I would have no idea. That was just some general advice :)

Comment: You have pieces of a solution here, so it appears you have an idea of how to do this. It's not clear to me what you are having trouble with. Can you be more specific on what the issue is you are having? Like what you tried and what error messages you are encountering, or that something isn't responding as you expect.

Comment: Look at using Guzzle and async promises to send all 10,000+ GET requests as a command that gets ran hourly. Be sure to set a sensible timeout. IMO, queues isn't a good option for this task. You want to know within a few minutes of resolving all requests what sites are online vs. offline (and probably alert you if your command failed).  When the problem is separated across queued jobs that may not have resolved yet, it becomes a lot harder to know whether your check (command) succeeded or failed as a whole.

Comment: I think you went about this the wrong way.

Check if a site is online only when retrieving the post.  (I'd recommend displaying the post, and calling an ajax function in js to request the site status).  I just cannot feasibly see why you would try to figure this out every hour.  How many of those 10,000 sites are going to be needed to be checked in a given hour?  10?50?100?1000?  

Search each site when the page is requested, store the result to cache for an hour for repeated requests.